# New email create event in outlook 2010 using C#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, plugins, outlook-2010

I am trying to create new email event in C# which works similar to new email message in outlook 2010 during loading outlook. But i could not get able to get name of event in outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code

```
this.Application.NewMailEx += new   Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailExEventHandler(olApp_NewMail);

private void olApp_NewMail(String itemCollection)
    {
     //write some code here
    }
```